# Show changes of a transaction in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'd like to know if a transaction actually causes any changes in a MySQL DB.

The first thing I tried is to see if the `ROLLBACK` command gives any hints, but it simply says `0 rows affected`:

```
mysql> START TRANSACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELETE FROM articles;
Query OK, 12 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> ROLLBACK;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Or is it possible to see any changes while in a transaction?

Comment: Use user-defined variable and summarize the amount of affected rows in it during transaction.

Comment: @Akina do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, val INT);
START TRANSACTION;
SET @counter := 0;
-- Insert 3 rows
INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
SET @counter := @counter + ROW_COUNT();
-- Update 2 of 3 rows, id = 2 and 3
-- But in one row initial and final value is the same
-- so by fact only one row is altered
UPDATE test SET val = 4 - val WHERE id > 1;
SET @counter := @counter + ROW_COUNT();
-- Delete 2 rows
DELETE FROM test WHERE id < 3;
SET @counter := @counter + ROW_COUNT();
COMMIT;
SELECT CONCAT('Total rows affected count = ', @counter) AS total;
```

> ```
> | total                         |
> | :---------------------------- |
> | Total rows affected count = 6 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00d174f7bd6fa505f969f5234b357084)*

Comment: Do you have an idea how to track changes in fields from an update query?

Comment: *track changes in fields from an update query* Use trigger-based logging. Or use MariaDB and versioning.